# How can I repopulate TextFields in JavaFX after switching from one fxml to another?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm building a very simple inventory management program in JavaFX as part of a school project. One of the requirements that I have been given is to have two different classes for parts, InHousePart and OutsourcedPart, both inherit from an abstract Part class. The two classes are identical except for one field: InHousePart has "machineID" and OutsourcedPart has "companyName". The second requirement is to have two FXML documents, one for each type of part, and I need to switch between them using a pair of radio buttons: In-House and Outsourced. When I switch from one to the other I need to repopulate the common fields from one to the other, however I can't seem to make it work.

The FXML files were built in SceneBuilder and each field has a unique name across both files. I've also verified that my Java code and the FXML are properly referencing each other.

From the Outsourced screen, the user is supposed to have the option to select In-House via the radio button and change the part type. Below is my field declarations and the method that is called when this radio button is selected.

```
@FXML
private RadioButton partInhouseOnInhouse;
@FXML
private TextField nameOnOutsourced;
@FXML
private TextField nameOnInhouse;
@FXML
private TextField costOnOutsourced;
@FXML
private TextField costOnInhouse;
@FXML
private TextField priceOnOutsourced;
@FXML
private TextField priceOnInhouse;
@FXML
private TextField inStockOnOutsourced;
@FXML
private TextField inStockOnInhouse;
@FXML
private TextField invMinOnOutsourced;
@FXML
private TextField invMinOnInhouse;
@FXML
private TextField invMaxOnOutsourced;
@FXML
private TextField invMaxOnInhouse;

@FXML
private void switchToInHouseFromOutsourced() throws IOException {

nameOnInhouse = nameOnOutsourced;
priceOnInhouse = priceOnOutsourced;
inStockOnInhouse = inStockOnOutsourced;
invMinOnInhouse = invMinOnOutsourced;
invMaxOnInhouse = invMaxOnOutsourced;
costOnInhouse = costOnOutsourced;

System.out.println(nameOnInhouse.getText());

Parent root = null;

partStage=(Stage) nameOnOutsourced.getScene().getWindow();
root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("modifyPart_Inhouse.fxml"));

Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    partStage.setScene(scene);

    partStage.show();
}
```

This is the FXML for "modifyPart_Outsourced.fxml". The "modifyPart_Inhouse.fxml" is nearly identical except for the fx:id's of the fields are named according to the declarations above.

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="inventory.view.modifyPartController">
   <children>
      <Text fx:id="title" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="27.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Modify Part" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <RadioButton fx:id="partInhouseOnOutsourced" layoutX="168.0" layoutY="15.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToInHouseFromOutsourcedOnOutsourced" text="In-House">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="parttype" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </RadioButton>
      <RadioButton fx:id="partOutsourceOnOutsourced" layoutX="316.0" layoutY="15.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToOutsourcedFromInhouseOnInhouse" selected="true" text="Outsourced" toggleGroup="$parttype" />
      <GridPane layoutX="21.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="147.0" prefWidth="461.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="60.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="132.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="130.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="200.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="170.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="116.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="47.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="156.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="108.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label text="ID" />
            <Label text="Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Cost" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label text="Price" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label text="In Stock" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <Label text="Inventory Min" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label text="Max" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label text="Company Name" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <TextField fx:id="partIDOnOutsourced" disable="true" editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="nameOnOutsourced" promptText="Part Name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Italic" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="costOnOutsourced" promptText="Cost" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Italic" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="priceOnOutsourced" promptText="Price" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Italic" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="inStockOnOutsourced" promptText="# in stock" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Italic" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="invMinOnOutsourced" promptText="Inventory Minimum" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Italic" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="invMaxOnOutsourced" promptText="Inventory Maximum" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Italic" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="companyName" promptText="Company Name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Italic" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <ButtonBar layoutX="286.0" layoutY="346.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <buttons>
          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSaveButton" text="Save" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCancelButton" text="Cancel" />
        </buttons>
      </ButtonBar>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I added the `System.out.println(nameOnInhouse.getText());` within the method to see if the field was being populated and the correct data is being fed out to the console, even though the field is blank. I also don't receive any errors and the new fxml loads just fine, but the fields are always blank.

If it weren't for the requirements I would look for a different way to do this other than switching the FXML, but it is what it is.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use the same controller class for the controllers for both FXMLs? It's almost certainly a mistake to do that - it gets confusing as you don't know which fields are initialized and which are still null. Start by creating a separate controller class for each FXML file. You should probably consider using a model which you can share between the controllers, and use to share the data among them.

Comment: @James_D Thank you for you comment! I was using one controller for both and you were correct, that was a mistake. Once I created a different controller for each FXML, the problem was easily resolved.